# Criar uma rotina no python que rode um script a cada 30 min

Tags: python

Criei um código que copia um arquivo de uma pasta e move para um outra, porém eu tenho arquivos a cada 30 min e preciso que esse script rode nesse tempo também.

Comment: Linux ou Windows? Já ouviu falar de tarefas agendadas?

Comment: Task Manager no Windows e Cron em sistemas Unix.

Answer (score 1):

se deseja fazer isso internamente por código, poderá utilizar a biblioteca `time`:

```
import time

while True:

    print('funcionou')

    time.sleep(1800)
```

A cada `n` segundos (`1800 segundos é o equivalente a 30 minutos`), o código que estiver no escopo do `while` será executada sempre que chegar no tempo designado. Para tanto, ficará com uma janela do terminal específica para que ele realize este processo, e para encerrar o fluxo você poderá usar um `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Também, tem a possibilidade de usar um agendamento de tarefas ou um `automator` para executar o `arquivo.py` sem a necessidade de deixá-lo rodando adormecido por meio do sleep.